# SSIS Parallel Tasks into single DFT

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to run multiple DFTs in parallel.  Each DFT will collect a record count and store it in a variable. Once all the DFTs are completed, I want the control flow to move to a final DFT that would assemble all counts and write those to a file. (All DFTs would funnel into this final DFT where the counts are handled.)

I'm familiar with running things in parallel, but I'm thinking as soon as the first DFT completes, it will kick off the final DFT before counts have been gathered for the rest of the original DFTs.

I would like for the package to wait until ALL DFTs have been completed to run the final DFT.  I was thinking having a variable that gets incremented, but you'd have to loop over that final DFT or else it would just fail the first time it hits that task in the control flow.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put all the Data Flow Tasks that you want to run in parallel into a Sequence Container and have the final Data Flow Task follow on from the Sequence Container.  The final Data Flow will only be triggered when everything in the Sequence Container has finished running.